# How to integrate REST API in IOS

Tags: objective-c, rest

My project need to implement REST API, but I don't know what is it and What is it used to?And it develop by Apple? Can you help me explain it more clear? It likes upload picture to Facebook, right? Last, can you show me how to integrate it into iOS app? Thanks

Comment: Dude, google is your friend. Simply view, REST is an interface. I think for this homework assignment you are likely "Targeting a RESTful service".  Odds are you're not building a service into your ios.  I'd consider building something that grabs the time off of NASA. it's a good test and requires little knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying this out :  RestKit: http://restkit.org/